# How to unzip a folder in google colab?

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I am trying to make an image classification task in Colab but after importing the dataset from the kaggle, the data comes in zip format. And when unzipped, the dataset is not giving a folder but giving a list of images. How can I get a folder outta it?

Comment: Are you getting the dataset into Colab directly from Kaggle? Or are you downloading the dataset and then uploading it to Colab?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you are using colab you can just use a `!` to send the kernel a bash command.

This means that something like this in a new cell should do the trick:

```
!unzip my_data.zip -d my_data
```

Comment: Thanks, but what does the -d means? is it the directory?

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help (if my answer resolved your issue you can always accept it). For the `-d` I think it means directory, yes: https://linux.die.net/man/1/unzip

Comment: @SubratSwain btw - if the answer resolved your issue you might consider accepting (and even upvoting) it? :-)

Comment: Here "d" means destination

Answer (score 8):

if I have downloaded a zip file in drive via Colab like this

```
!wget 'http://nlp.stanford.edu/data/glove.840B.300d.zip'
```

it will go by default to '/content'

then I need to unzip like this and bring in my destination folder -d

```
!unzip '/content/glove.840B.300d.zip' -d '/content/drive/My Drive/data'
```

'/content/drive/My Drive/data' ==> destination folder within drive

remember whatever is in '/content' will be removed once you shut down the system or go offline, to save it permanently within drive, give path like '/content/drive/My Drive/data'